# How to access the Public property of aspx page in the custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a Custom control and embedded in the aspx page.
Now i want to access a public property in the aspx webpage in the Custom Control (eg: Test.ascx.cs)
How i can do that?

TIA

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far :)

Comment: ...ascx.cs is not a custom control, it's a user control.

Answer (score 0):

It would not make much sense to add dependency from the custom control to the outside.

Create an interface that contains the property you specified :

```
public interface IMyPageInterface 
{
   string MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

implement interface on your page :

```
//your page code behind
public partial class WebForm1: System.Web.UI.Page,IMyPageInterface
{
    public string MyProperty 
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}
```

you can get your page as IMyPageInterface in your custom control

```
IMyPageInterface myPage = this.Page as IMyPageInterface;
myPage.MyProp...
```

A property of type IMyPageInterface can also be defined

```
public class MyControl :Control
{
    public IMyPageInterface MyPage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Page as IMyPageInterface;
        }
    }
}
```